# Share computed property code

Tags: ember.js

In have a Users_Index view where I render all users. For each user I want to show a computed property. I do this in the corresponding ItemController. The code:

```
// app/controllers/users/index.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'user'
});
```

---

```
// app/controllers/user.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({    
  myComputedProperty: function(){
    // just example nonsense here
    return this.get('name') + ' and ' + this.get('id');
  }.property('name', 'id')
});
```

---

```
// app/templates/users/index.hbs
<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li>
      {{myComputedProperty}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Now I have the User_Show view and want to use the computed property there as well. For sure I don't want to repeat the computed property code in the `users/show controller`. Can anyone give me a hint what is the right way in Ember to share the code? A mixin? A component? Add the function to the user model (that sounds totally wrong)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a mixin like this:

```
App.ComputedProperty = Ember.Mixin.Create({
   myComputedProperty: function(){
      // just example nonsense here
      return this.get('name') + ' and ' + this.get('id');
   }.property('name', 'id')
}};
```

And then add it to your controller like this

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(App.ComputedProperty, function() {
   . . . 
});
```

Give the API a read [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html).

Or, you can add the computed property to your User Model instead, like this:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
   name: DS.attr(
   myComputedProperty: function(){
      // just example nonsense here
      return this.get('name') + ' and ' + this.get('id');
   }.property('name', 'id')
});
```

Then you can access it every where you access a User Model.

Comment: In your opinion, what is the cleanest way to implement it? Mixin or add it to the model?

Comment: If you're only going to need it on the one model, then the model is probably easier. If you need it on multiple controllers after that, then probably the mixin.